# Aligning Excel correlation window with Pandas correlation window

Tags: python, excel, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation

I created a rolling correlation in EXCEL using a 3 period window for Var_1 and Var_2.The Excel code is :

```
=CORREL(B2:B4,C2:C4)
```

I am trying to create the same result in Python. However, when I execute the code, my results are shifted down 1 row in Python. I also get a 1.0 as the first row value, which I don't understand.
The sheet is read into Python from Excel and saved as a pandas dataframe.
Here is the image.[image: Excel Spreadsheet snippet]
The python code I created to recreate this rolling correlation.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame((df.iloc[::1,1]).rolling(window = 3,min_periods = 1,center = True).corr((df.iloc[::1,2])))
```

[image: Python Results showing row shift]

Answer (score 1):

you could probably use the stats module with list comprehension:

```
df['r_value'] = [scipy.stats.linregress(df['Var_1'].loc[i:i+2], df['Var_2'].loc[i:i+2])[2] for i in range(len(df))]

    Var_1   Var_2   r_value
0   5        -55    -0.525909
1   41       -44    -0.455413
2   85       -65    0.032059
3   55       -77    0.896258
4   65       -25    0.388874
5   47       -77    0.474843
6   25       -48    1.000000
7   63       -12    0.000000
```